# How to reproduce this sound

Tags: synthesizer, fl-studio

I really like the "slidey" synthesizer you can hear in

at 1:00

Seems like it should be really simple... but I've tried lots of different things in Sytrus (I'm using FL Studio). How can I reproduce this sound (I don't care about the volume / cutoff envelopes or melody, just the sound) using Sytrus?

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, it is very simple. I don't have FL Studio but I can point out a few things about the timbre, after analyzing a clean sample:

1. Since both even and odd harmonics of the wave are present and well distributed, start with a **Saw wave.** Most of my answer is based on the **G#4 note (octave).** Basically there are two octaves in the song that the sound plays at.
2. There is a resonance in the upper partials, experiment with a filter spike around 5khz, a good bet is Resonance from a Low Pass filter (dampening above this frequency).
3. The low frequency harmonics (below G#6) are flatter than usual however, which gives a brighter sound. So you could try a shallow -6dB high pass filter from about 1.5khz. Depending on the original synth used, there may have bee a filter bias, where you can create a resonance and shift the upper vs lower spectrum higher or lower all at once (FM8, Synthmaster).
4. It's challenging to examine the lower notes, so you could try strong Key Scaling on the Low Pass filter and/or a soft kind of Tube saturation to warm up the low register.
5. The expression (envelopes, pitch bend/portamento, cutoff) is still quite important to 'this' sound and will require some experimentation.

Comment: "Its quite simple....here is a vague complicated explanation"....Well Put!

Comment: Essentially. Our ears are good at fooling us. I'm pointing out that with Additive/Subtractive synthesis, a lot of sound types are more accessible than we think. I've given a few answers on this subject where musicians/sound designers attempt to complicate it further. Have a go!

Comment: I didn't find this explanation vague at all. It seems pretty clear and a good starting point for reconstructing this patch.